# Django + alwaysdata.com Noob Question

Tags: python, django

I'm learning Django and working on sample sites.. I registered at alwaysdata but am unable to view the site after I go 'manage.py runserver' in the SSH (this is after I've created the project and navigated to the appropriate directory, of course).

I appreciate any help.

Thanks

Comment: With no error messages or log, we're hard-pressed to guess what you problem is.  ESP not working today.  Perhaps you have a hint you could share?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you taken a look at the [wiki entry regarding the django dev server](http://wiki.alwaysdata.com/wiki/Utiliser_le_serveur_de_d%C3%A9veloppement_int%C3%A9gr%C3%A9_de_Django)?  Google translate seems to indicate that you need to request some ports open first, and that once you've got them assigned you can pass in one of those port numbers to `runserver` to run it on that port.

If you need the translated-to-English version, [here's a link](http://translate.google.com/translate?js=n&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&layout=2&eotf=1&sl=fr&tl=en&u=http://wiki.alwaysdata.com/wiki/Utiliser_le_serveur_de_d%25C3%25A9veloppement_int%25C3%25A9gr%25C3%25A9_de_Django)

Answer (score 3):

I am also an alwaysdata customer. Daniel DiPaolo gave you the right links to get it working on ssh with the dev server. The google translation seems correct to me. You need to request a port range in order to use the dev server on ssh.

But this is intended only for debugging purpose and should run for a short while.

Here is how to deploy with fastCGI which is the regular way to deploy a Django site on alwaysdata.

http://wiki.alwaysdata.com/wiki/D%C3%A9ployer_une_application_Django.

Google give a [decent translation](http://translate.google.fr/translate?hl=fr&sl=fr&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwiki.alwaysdata.com%2Fwiki%2FD%25C3%25A9ployer_une_application_Django)

AlwaysData is running a forum at http://forum.alwaysdata.com/ mostly in French but questions in English are welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

The devserver included with django is for testing purposes, only on your local machine and should not be used on a web host. From the docs:

> DO NOT USE THIS SERVER IN A PRODUCTION
>   SETTING. It has not gone through
>   security audits or performance tests.
>   (And that's how it's gonna stay. We're
>   in the business of making Web
>   frameworks, not Web servers, so
>   improving this server to be able to
>   handle a production environment is
>   outside the scope of Django.)

If i have somehow misinterpreted your question, i apologise.

Comment: I believe he's asking for development purposes not for production purposes.  At least, I hope he is...

It's perfectly okay to have a remotely accessible development server running, as long as it's not exactly well publicized and not kept running all the time.

Comment: I hope thats the case. But just out of curiosity, since im learning too, why would you run the devsever on a webhost?

Comment: Perhaps because that is the only environment available with the same specs? Not a big deal to run dev on a web host. Many people do it all the time.

Answer (score 1):

When you enter **manage.py runserver** you're running the development web server on the [loopback interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loopback) (127.0.0.1). You could test this out by running **wget 127.0.0.1** on the same server that the development web server is running.

If you want it to be on the internet so you could access it from outside that server, you'd have to specify your public ip. For example, to run the web development server on ip 1.1.1.1 and port 8080 (personally recommend using a non-standard port):

```
manage.py runserver 1.1.1.1:8080
```

To find out your public ip, try running **ifconfig** on SSH.

Also, you might have to check out the firewall settings with your ISP/server provider.